# date-fns giving different values while calling startOfWeek in react native and webbrowser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web, date-fns

I am using datefns for web and react native to identify the start and end of current week.

On React Native, this is the code and output:

```
    const date = new Date()
    console.log(`today is ${date}`)
    console.log(startOfWeek(date));
    console.log(endOfWeek(date))

    LOG  today is Mon Apr 10 2023 12:16:50 GMT+0530
    LOG  2023-04-08T18:30:00.000Z
    LOG  2023-04-15T18:29:59.999Z
```

On web here is the code and output:

```
const date = new Date();
const weekStartDate = startOfWeek(date);
const weekEndDate = endOfWeek(date);
console.log(`today is ${date}`)
console.log(`${weekStartDate}`)
console.log(`${weekEndDate}`)

today is Mon Apr 10 2023 12:26:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
NewsCurator.tsx:35 Sun Apr 09 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
NewsCurator.tsx:36 Sat Apr 15 2023 23:59:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I can see the time zone difference, but how can I make sure it is always working in a specific time zone across the devices and platforms? For me it is super important to have same timezone across devices as I am naming firestore collections using this.

Comment: If I copy the web code in react native it works same e.g it shows weekstart and end date in same time zone but what is the difference in storing the date in variable and printing it or instead calling startOfWeek() in console.log?

Comment: What you mean by web? web browser? web server? Are you sure date-fns in both places have the same version?

Comment: I think the time zone is the same, just the formatting is different

Comment: version is same, I installed latest version. I think it is due to toString conversion which is different in these cases:
1. console.log(startOfWeek(date));
2. const weekStartDate = startOfWeek(date); console.log(`${weekStartDate}`)

Not sure what is different in 1 & 2 which is causing this issue.

Comment: Can you check what "startOfWeek(new Date()) instanceof Date" returns in both places

Comment: Usually the difference is that: `\`${something}\`` here something.toString() is being called, while using directly the value might return something different. Like `typeof new Date()` is object and `typeof \`${new Date()}\`` is string